# How can I play a specific frequency in music21?

Tags: python, music21

I want to play music in Music21 in frequencies that aren't in the 12 tone Western musical scale.  Is there a way to do this?  .show('midi') rounds the frequency to the nearest semitone.  Are there any other ways to play music with specific frequencies?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full-featured MIDI app on your computer, try:

```
n = note.Note(type='whole')
n.pitch.frequency = 428.0  # A-half-flat
n.show('midi')  # or n.write('midi') if you do not have MIDI playback configured at all.
```

On pre-Catalina macs, the QuickTime 7 player will play this back correctly.  From Catalina onwards, I do not have a good free solution (the great free MIDI replacement APPlay.app does not seem to support pitch bends.  Windows Media Player does.  As do a number of notation apps).

Alternatively install `pygame` and look at the `music21.midi.realtime` demo to see how to get non-12-tone playback using it.

Unfortunately, the last ten years have been worse and worse for MIDI support; what was easy in 2010 is so much harder in 2021.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That's all super helpful.

I was trying code just like you wrote and am using a post-Catalina mac -- so that explains why it's rounding to nearest semitone I guess.  A shame that MIDI support is getting worse, but I'll check out pygame.  Wow -- and you made music21?  It's fantastic.  Thanks again!

Comment: APPlay.app is now supporting pitch-bends (or always did and just wasn't working on my system).  Garageband will also do it, I believe.